# Url to serve log file Glassfish 4

Tags: java, glassfish

Let's say I have a webapp on a Glassfish 4 server, which logs under `${com.sun.aas.instanceRoot}/logs/Application` in `webapp.log`.

How can I serve this log file in the browser?

I can serve it easily if I have for instance a REST endpoint and return

`new File("${com.sun.aas.instanceRoot}/logs/Application/webapp.log");`,

but I want to also access it if I don't have a `.war` with such an endpoint on the server - I only have an EJB jar which logs into that file and I want to serve it in the browser.

Comment: Many thanks to [Adam Bien](http://www.adam-bien.com/) for answering this question during his [29th airhacks.tv Q&A](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CzPoCjIpcwA).